# Apache WSGI python needs restart

Tags: python, linux, apache, ubuntu

I have set up an Apache server to run a python app.
I have set up an VirtualHost (port 8080) in sites-available and ran a2ensite on it.
Created .wsgi file in my project.
Restarted the server and now all works great.

The server needs to write some files and the project is in /home/user/folder

The problem is that when i restart the server i can access a link (/test) and it works but when i try to access (/generate) the files are not created.

I think that there is a problem with the permissions?
Can you help me figure it out?

sites available

```
Listen 8080
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    WSGIDaemonProcess FlaskApp user=www-data group=www-data threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/pdfuser/pdf/node_transform/hello.wsgi
    <Directory /home/pdfuser/pdf/node_transform/>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
    Alias /static /home/pdfuser/pdf/node_transform/static
    <Directory /home/pdfuser/pdf/node_transform/static/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You're running the process as user www-data, but the project lives in /home/pdfuser. Is pdfuser a member of the www-data group, perhaps?

Comment: Nevermind, the bug was on my side. I had a command in crontab which started a process on 8080 and apache couldn't bid it. My mistake. Also thank you for respons

Comment: Unrelated, but your configuration is faulty. You are using WSGIDaemonProcess to create a daemon process group but not then using WSGIProcessGroup to delegate your WSGI application to run it. See http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/why-are-you-using-embedded-mode-of.html